# Replace a string with another recursively in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run below sh file but getting error.

```sh
Var1="//abcdef"

Var2="//mnbvcx"

find ./ \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/{$Var1}/{$Var2}/g"
```

Error message -

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown option to `s'
```

Also while executing I want to the contents of the sh file not to change.

Comment: Use `sed -i "s~$Var1~$Var2~g"`

Comment: `Var1` and `Var2` contain the `'/'` character that is special to `sed`. They will need to be escaped, e.g. `Var1="\/\/abcdef"` (or as @anubhava shows you can use an alternative delimiter)